# How to substring in Excel between different characters?

Tags: excel, substring, formula

first-time poster so please bear with me. I am trying to convince Excel to do a substring and failing miserably. The task is simple enough on the surface of it, extract text that's between a fixed set of chars (+, -, * and /), basically mathematical operators.
My input string looks like this:

A+B+C+D

Now, if my string looks like that, or like A-B-C-D, all is good, I can use this and it works (not my code, found on https://exceljet.net/formula/split-text-with-delimiter and modified to suit my needs:

```
First text: TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"+",REPT(" ",LEN($A2))),0*LEN($A2)+1,LEN($A2)))
Second: TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"+",REPT(" ",LEN($A2))),1*LEN($A2)+1,LEN($A2)))
Third: TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"+",REPT(" ",LEN($A2))),2*LEN($A2)+1,LEN($A2)))
Forth: TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"+",REPT(" ",LEN($A2))),3*LEN($A2)+1,LEN($A2)))
```

And all is good, until I have a string like: A-B+C-D or wahtever combo, basically not all the same char.
I tried using Find and Search in different configurations, but I always come to the same problem:

1. Using substitute gives me the n'th occurance and that's no good as - may be my second symbol or third
2. Can't dynamically and accurately calculate the length for MID, as it does Nr. of chars, not "until"

I can't use VB script for security reasons, so I am stuck trying to use Excel formulas.
It HAS to be one formula, as in the end, it's part of a bigger formula that's something like this:

```
CONCATENATE(IF(ISNUMBER(A),A,VLOOKUP(A)),IF(ISNUMBER(A),A,VLOOKUP(A)),IF(ISNUMBER(A),A,VLOOKUP(A)),IF(ISNUMBER(A),A,VLOOKUP(A)))
```

So I have the input in a cell and my result has to do all the processing in an adjacent cell.
Thank you in advance, at whit's end over here.

Comment: `FILTERXML()` may help you. Put some sample from your actual data rather that `A+B+C+D` then show your expected output.

Comment: Also mention your excel version.

Comment: It would be very helpful to put a list of example input and output data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `FILTERXML()` function.

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"+","|"),"-","|"),"*","|"),"/","|"),"|","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))
```

[image]

If you are not on `Excel365` then try below formula.

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"+","|"),"-","|"),"*","|"),"/","|"),"|","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[" & COLUMN(A1) &"]")
```

To learn `FILTERXML()` go through [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837697/5514747) from @JvdV

Comment: Yes, nice! Provided you have 65 and if you don't want to nest too many `SUBSTITUTE()` in the future, you could try: `=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&CONCAT(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),"+-*/")),"</s><s>",MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)))&"</s></t>","//s"))` or if `LET()` is available: `=LET(X,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&CONCAT(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(X,"+-*/")),"</s><s>",X))&"</s></t>","//s")))` =) ++

Comment: Beautiful, just beautiful. Works perfectly. I will read the article you linked, hopefully, I won't have to reask. I see how my question was a bit ... lax on details. I only need not to figure out how I can get each one individually to implement in my other formula.

Comment: Figured it out: "//s[position()=x]". THANK YOU HARUN !!!

Answer (score 0):

For lower versions of Excel following formula would work by copying across as much as needed:

`=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(" "&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"+"," "),"-"," "),"/"," "),"*"," ")," ",REPT(" ",99)),99*COLUMNS($A1:A1),99))`

which is fairly similar to what has been posted on Exceljet site.